# Backing up Android keystore using Expo - Do we need to save the associated passwords?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, keystore, android-keystore

When you run `expo fetch:android:keystore` it shows the follow:

```
Configuring credentials for myApp in project myApp
Keystore credentials
  Keystore password: 1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef
  Key alias:         1234567890abcdef1234567890abcd==
  Key password:      1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef

  Path to Keystore:  C:\projects\myApp\myApp.jks
```

**My question is, do we need to separately store the passwords and alias, or only the `.jks` file?**

This is not made clear in the [relevant Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/#3-start-the-build).

Comment: Bro you saved me!! I didnt know that I can get the keystore like this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**you need both**, when you build the same apk with a different expo account, you have to run:

```
expo build:android
```

then you have to configure your credentials choosing "I want to upload my own file".

you have to use your file.jks

and enter your alias an passwords info.

---

In case you've already set a wrong key, run:

```
expo build:android --clear-credentials
```

Comment: Could you please help me? I'm facing the same situation, I have the original jks file and I'm trying to upload a new version of the app, but through a new Expo account, due to I'm a new developer. I tried "expo build:android --clear-credentials", entered the data provided after "expo fetch:android:keystore", but it fails; trhowing "Make sure that you provided correct credentials in 'credentials.json' and the path provided under 'keystorePath' points to a valid keystore file"